# How to make a custom facebook login button using Facebook sdk 4.7.0 in android and a custom Google Plus login button

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, facebook-login, google-plus-signin

I am building an android app using facebook login and google plus login. and I am finding it hard to make custom buttons for both of these. Is there a way to change it?

I am using android studio 1.4 and using gradle dependencies to add g+ and fb login like this

```
dependencies 
{
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

Comment: please post some images or links to your wireframes or mockups of custom buttons that you want.

Comment: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFY_0_aihQASVhYSnVBZWV0WEE/view?usp=sharing"

image on top is what i want to achieve, below is what I am currently achieving @vipul_asri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fblogin_button_selector.xml** in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color_pressed" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Custom FB Login Button** in your layout.

```
 <Button
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/login"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_50"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_50"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon"
   android:textSize="@dimen/sp_15"
   android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_background"
   android:text="Connect "
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

output :

[image]

Using this you can also implement G+ Login Button.

Comment: i was using this button, can i use the default Button?
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_weight=".45"
android:background="@drawable/fblogin_button_selector"/>

@vipul_asri

Comment: @NilabjaMukherjee no i have tried using default button to customize it, but it doesn't have much flexibility to make it entirely as you require

Comment: okay, thanks for the help will try to implement it later @vipul_asri

Answer (score 1):

For me, this solution works,

**button on xml**

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
        android:longClickable="false" />
```

Change on **styles.xml**,

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, but I needed custom background so had to use selectors

Comment: I understand your choice, with selectors You can change the background. @NilabjaMukherjee